# Pound Sign in JPA Field Name

Tags: java, jpa

Our database contains a lot of fields with a `pound sign (#)` in the field name. If we try to use a native query in `JPA` it treats the `# as a parameter`. Here is an example:

```
public List<?> getRecordList(String sql){
    Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql);
    return query.getResultList();
}

List<?> r = getRecordList("SELECT VENDOR.\"ve#\", ITEM.\"item#\" FROM ITEM LEFT JOIN VENDOR ON ITEM.\"itemve#\" = VENDOR.\"ve#\");
```

When this is executed we receive the following error:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3).
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT VENDOR."ve?, ITEM."item? FROM ITEM LEFT JOIN VENDOR ON ITEM."itemve? = VENDOR."ve?
```

Comment: I think the solution here is to rename your column names... who the hell came up with the idea to use `#` in column names?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option. We are dealing with a large AS400 database that has been in place for 20+ years. This is an issue that we have with several hundred tables. This is a very common naming method with legacy systems.

Comment: why you don't use jpql instead of native query? is there a special reason?

Answer (score 1):

If you use JPQL it works but a native query does not.